# BibTeX styles with the class amsart

Tags: bibtex, natbib, amsart

I have a quick question for **BibTeX** wizards who are familiar with **amsart** class. Namely, I am writing a paper with my buddy who is a Geophysicist. On the other hand, I am a mathematician with a knee-jerk reaction to use **amsart** for everything I write. I need to comply with the following.

> Citations. Citations in the text should appear by the name(s) of the
> author(s), followed by the year of publication in parentheses, e.g.,
> Hough and Martin (2002).

To my limited knowledge, AMS doesn't have a style that conforms to the above specification. I tried `natbib` package and [**plainnat**](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles) style and it seems to do the trick. Am I missing anything? Is there a simpler way to conform to the above specification without using a separate package for BibTeX styles?

Comment: The citation/bibliography requirements from the journal are not nearly enough to completely define a citation and bibliography style, so it's anyone's guess if `plainnat` will make the journal happy, but it should be able to produce citations like this. I guess the bigger question is if and how the journal you want to submit to accepts LaTeX submissions (often journals that do have a journal template or at least some guidance for LaTeX users telling them what to do with the bibliography)

Comment: @Mico Now that is embarrassing but it is fixed now. Obviously English is not my mother tongue. Even after 25 years, I make silly mistakes. Please don't tell that to my daughters. They are trying really hard to fix my English.

Comment: @moewe BSSA is a strange beast. They do accept LaTeX submission but they don't provide a template.  https://www.seismosoc.org/publications/bssa-submission-guidelines/ Also LaTeX suggestions https://www.seismosoc.org/publications/latex-suggestions/. I have never understood them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site https://www.seismosoc.org/publications/bssa-submission-guidelines/, mentioned in your comment to @moewe, provides the following guidelines for how three types of bibliographic entries -- `@article`, `@book`, and `@incollection` -- should be formatted:

[image]

I don't think that either `plainnat` or `abbrvnat` provide decent approximations to these guidelines. The `apalike` bib style doesn't provide a perfect match either, but IMNSHO it does provide a reasonable first approximation. (If you need help adapting the `apalike` bib style to bold-face the `volume` number in entries of type `@article`, please post a separate question.)

Incidentally, for reasons I don't claim to understand, I could *not* get the code shown below to compile correctly when using the `amsart` document class. However, it compiles fine under the `article` class.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % select a suitable document class
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{hough-martin:2002,
  author   = "Hough, Susan E. and Stacey Martin",
  year     = 2002,
  title    = "Magnitude estimates of two large aftershocks of 
              the 16 {December} 1811 {New Madrid} earthquake", 
  journal  = "Bull.\ Seism.\ Soc.\ Am.",
  volume   = 92,
  pages    = "3259-3268",
}
@book{gutenberg:1959,
  author   = "Gutenberg, Beno",
  year     = 1959,
  title    = "Physics of the Earth's Interior", 
  publisher="Academic Press", 
  address  = "New York", 
  pages    = "111-113",
}
@incollection{laster-etal:1967,
  author   = "Laster, Stanley J. and Milo M. Backus and Richard Schell",
  year     = 1967,
  title    = "Analog mode studies of the simple refraction problem",
  booktitle="Seismic Refraction Prospecting",
  editor   = "Albert W. Musgrave", 
  publisher="Society of Exploration Geophysics", 
  address  = "Tulsa, Oklahoma",
  pages    = "15-66",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\setlength\bibhang{0pt} % optional
\setlength\bibsep{1ex}  % optional
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```